# How to give focus to DateTimeFormField on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, focus, textformfield

I have a form with TextFormFields. I can give focus to next field using Tab key as usual. But, it skips DateTimeFormField. How can I make it show the Date picker instead of skipping it when it is its turn?

Did some search but couldn't find anything near it.

[image]

Here is my code samples. I simply use TextFormField's and DateTimeFormField inside a Column. But there is no focus option for DateTimeFormField.

```js
    class FormDialog extends ConsumerWidget {
  const FormDialog({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        CustomTextField(
          labelText: firstName,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        CustomTextField(
          labelText: lastName,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        CustomDateField(
          labelText: dateOfBirth,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        CustomTextField.email(
          labelText: parentEmail,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


    class CustomDateField extends StatelessWidget {
      const CustomDateField({
        Key? key,
        this.labelText,
        this.hintText,
      }) : super(key: key);
      final String? labelText;
      final String? hintText;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DateTimeFormField(
          mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
          dateFormat: DateFormat.yMd(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: labelText,
            hintText: hintText,
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
            helperText: ' ',
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
      const CustomTextField({
        Key? key,
        this.labelText,
        this.icon,
        this.textInputAction,
      }) : super(key: key);
      final String? labelText;
      final TextFieldIcon? icon;
      final TextInputAction? textInputAction;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextFormField(
          autovalidateMode:   AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: labelText,
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
            prefixIcon: icon,
            helperText: ' ',
          ),
          textInputAction: textInputAction,
        );
      }

      factory CustomTextField.email({
        String? errorMessage,
        String? labelText,
      }) =>
          CustomTextField(
            labelText: labelText ?? email,
            icon: const TextFieldIcon.email(),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          );
    }
```

Comment: Please offer some code to further help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the package's Github repository, it is built upon FormField, creating and initializing a FocusNode and passing the focus node to the widget might resolve the issue. If not you might need to implement your own form field.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no focus node parameter for DateTimeFormField. That was the first thing I've checked. Looks like I need to implement my own field. Thanks for the answer.